# How to get non-negative solutions to matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve the equation `AX = B` in R.

I have two matrices, `A` and `B`:

```
A = matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,
     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,
     0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
     0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
     0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
     0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,
     1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0), byrow = T, nrow = 10, ncol = 16)

B = matrix(c(1900,2799,3096,3297,3782,4272,7783,10881,7259,30551), nrow = 10, ncol = 1)
```

My question is, how can I solve `AX = B` and be guaranteed a non-negative solution? The values I am solving for (`X1, X2,...X15, X16`) are population figures so they cannot be negative. Ideally, they would be integer values as well but one thing at a time.

Is there an easy way to do this in R?

I have found one way to do it here but it doesn't yield a positive result for all `X` which is what I'm after.

Comment: I found a solution using the `nnls` package. The solution is (1900, 0, 3297, 0, 0, 4272, 10881, 0, 3782, 0, 2799, 0, 109, 2987, 7783, 0). However, I know that roughly speaking `X1` should be ~600 and `X2` should be ~1300. Is there anyway to include this logic in R? (By possibly putting constraints on `X1` (saying it must be >500 let's say) and `X2` (saying it must be >1200)?

Comment: You haven't provided quite enough information for this to be answerable.  Please explain what you mean by "solve," given that your constraints make it unlikely that any $X$ can be found for which $AX=B$.  For instance, are you looking for a least-squares solution?

Comment: How does  600        1300           0        3297        1610        2662    10881           0        3782           0        2799           0        3096           0   7783           0 grab you? That exactly meets all of your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

rank(A) = $9$, which means that the null space of $A$ has dimension $7$.  So $Ax=B$ has a 7-fold infinity of exact solutions, if we don't worry about restricting $x$ to integer or non-negative values.  There are still am enormous number of solutions to $Ax=B$ in which $x$ is restricted to be all non-negative integers.

It is not difficult to find that
$x = $

```
 600
1300
   0
3297
1610
2662
10881
    0
 3782
   0
 2799
    0
 3096
    0
 7783
    0
```

exactly solves $Ax=B$, has $x \ge 0$, all x integer, $x(1) = 600$, and $x(2) = 1300$, which exactly meets all of your requirements, to include those stated in your comment that you want  $x(1)$ ~ $600$, and $x(2)$ ~ $1300$.

I found the above solution by formulating and solve an Integer Quadratic Programming problem in which the objective function being minimized is $(x1)-600)^2 + (x(2)-1300)^2$, subject to the constraints $Ax=B$, $x \ge 0$, x integer. And the result was an objective value of zero, i.e., a perfect meeting of your requirements. Actually, I obtained this same solution, solving it as a Quadratic Programming problem without the integer restriction. As it turns out, since there was a "perfect" solution, I could have avoided going to a Quadratic Programming formulation, if I had incorporated  $x(1) = 600$, and $x(2) = 1300$ as constraints, instead of  using $(x1)-600)^2 + (x(2)-1300)^2$ as a quadratic objective function. Actually, with this $A$ and $B$, it is possible to find exact solutions for for any of the 1901 combinations of $x(1)$ and $x(2)$ such that they are nonnegative and $x(1) + x(2) = 1900$.

But now, focusing on solutions in which $x(1) = 600$ and $x(2) = 1300$, there are still an enormous number of nonnegative integer solutions to $Ax = B$.  And these solutions differ, in some cases by very large amounts, in various of the other elements. Whether this should matter to you I suppose depends on what you're actually trying to do, which I have no idea. Or put another way, your problem is very degenerate (has many degrees of freedom). You could further narrow possible solutions by adding additional constraints and/or incorporating solution preference into an objective function to be optimized.

You want a solution with the largest value of $x(16)$? O.k,

```
  600  
 1300     
 3297     
    0        
 4272         
    0     
10881      
    0        
 3782         
    0       
 2799       
    0       
 3096       
    0
 1824     
 5959
```

Oh, maybe you want $x(4) = 28$ and $x(16) = 492$? Not a prob, Bob.

```
 600
1300
3269
  28
   0
4272
9714
1167
3782
   0
2799
   0
3096
   0
7291
 492
```